# Bad wkhtmltopdf's path for wicked_pdf and wkhtmltopdf

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, spree, wicked-pdf

I am using two Gems to convert HTML to PDF.

Using "https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf"

```
gem 'wicked_pdf'
gem "wkhtmltopdf-binary"
```

/initializer/wicked_pdf.rb

```
WickedPdf.config = {
  exe_path =>  "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
}
```

**What path should I use for the exe_path ?**

Comment: are you using windows?

Comment: @test no i am using ubuntu.

Comment: Do `which wkhtmltopdf` in your project directory terminal. It will give you path. Paste that path in config/initializers/wicked_pdf.rb and then restart your server

Comment: @test same error after i pass path which is get after which wkhtmltopdf

Answer (score 18):

`which wkhtmltopdf`

This will give you path of your wkhtmltopdf. You should copy this path and paste in your config/intializers/wicked_pdf.rb And then restart your server.

Comment: Worked for me. love you my dude

Answer (score 5):

Add this to `config/initializers/wicked_pdf.rb` ensuring your correct `GEM_HOME` is being referenced:

```
WickedPdf.config = {
  :exe_path => "#{ENV['GEM_HOME']}/bin/wkhtmltopdf"
}
```

This way you wont be hard coding any paths.

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort with this. It was a super annoying issue

Answer (score 5):

`config/initializers/wicked_pdf.rb`

```
path = `which wkhtmltopdf`.gsub(/\n/, "")

WickedPdf.config = { exe_path: path }
```

Comment: Although your code snippet might solve the issue, you should describe what’s the purpose of your code (how it solves the problem). Furthermore, you might want to check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer