# Im getting 'Error: PDF could not be generated! Bad CPU type in executable' on my m1 macbook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apple-m1

I have tests with wicked_pdf and wkhtmltopdf-binary. Both gems are installed, but errors dont go away :(
Im tried to install gems with Rosetta, but nothing helps me

error is here

```
Minitest::UnexpectedError:
       RuntimeError: Failed to execute:
       ["/Users/larkin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/bin/wkhtmltopdf", "--lowquality", "--footer-center", "конфіденційно", "--footer-left", "Служба етичного контролю", "--footer-right", "[page] / [topage]", "--footer-font-size", "10", "file:////var/folders/sk/3493jp896vj_spzzn_z2zvkm0000gn/T/wicked_pdf20211129-63903-gn9oc5.html", "/var/folders/sk/3493jp896vj_spzzn_z2zvkm0000gn/T/wicked_pdf_generated_file20211129-63903-urbrlu.pdf"]
       Error: PDF could not be generated!
        Command Error: /Users/larkin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/wkhtmltopdf-binary-0.12.5.4/bin/wkhtmltopdf:50:in `exec': Bad CPU type in executable - /Users/larkin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/wkhtmltopdf-binary-0.12.5.4/bin/wkhtmltopdf_macos_carbon (Errno::EBADARCH)
        from /Users/larkin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/wkhtmltopdf-binary-0.12.5.4/bin/wkhtmltopdf:50:in `<top (required)>'
        from /Users/larkin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/bin/wkhtmltopdf:23:in `load'
        from /Users/larkin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/bin/wkhtmltopdf:23:in `<main>'
        from /Users/larkin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `eval'
        from /Users/larkin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Did you try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/30646257

Comment: @Vishal   exe_path: '/Users/larkin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/bin/wkhtmltopdf',
yep(

Comment: Do you have apple m1 chip? I have the same issue on my macbook

Answer (score 6):

The installation/update of Rosetta (on MacOS Monterey 12.2) solved this issue for me with the following command :

```
softwareupdate --install-rosetta
```

Maybe it can help others

Comment: Rosetta helps to run apps which are supported for intel chips on MacOS. Thank you @SLgz for this answer, it worked for me.

I figured out the problem when I saw this error:  
bad CPU type in executable: wkhtmltopdf

Comment: it works for M2 as well

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue on macbook with apple m1 chip.
In order to fix that, you need to manually download binary for arm chip, for newest release (0.12.6) just go to: https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/packaging/releases/0.12.6-1
and download: `wkhtmltox-0.12.6-1.macos-cocoa.pkg`

Then install script and edit your `wicked_pdf.rb` file to point to newly installed binary:

```
WickedPdf.config = {
  exe_path: '/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf',
}
```

You can also do some changes to keep previous behavior on other machines, and use non gem binary only when already installed:

```
if File.exist?('/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf')
  binary_path = '/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf'
else
  binary_path = Gem.bin_path('wkhtmltopdf-binary', 'wkhtmltopdf')
end

WickedPdf.config = {
  exe_path: binary_path,
}
```